# How would I tidy this code into a loop in java?

Tags: java, string, tags, extract

```
 public class TagHandler {

private final String START = "<START ";
private final String END = "<END ";


    public String handleTag(String buf, String[] attrList) {  

     String startPattern1 = START+attrList[0]+">";
    String endPattern1 = END+attrList[0]+">";

    String startPattern2 = START+attrList[1]+">";
    String endPattern2 = END+attrList[1]+">";

    String startPattern3 = START+attrList[2]+">";
    String endPattern3 = END+attrList[2]+">";

    String startPattern4 = START+attrList[3]+">";
    String endPattern4 = END+attrList[3]+">";

    String startPattern5 = START+attrList[4]+">";
    String endPattern5 = END+attrList[4]+">";


           String extract1 = new String(buf);
    String extract2 = new String(buf);
    String extract3 = new String(buf);
    String extract4 = new String(buf);
    String extract5 = new String(buf);

            extract1 = extract1.substring(extract1.indexOf(startPattern1)+startPattern1.length(), extract1.indexOf(endPattern1));
    extract2 = extract2.substring(extract2.indexOf(startPattern2)+startPattern2.length(), extract2.indexOf(endPattern2));
    extract3 = extract3.substring(extract3.indexOf(startPattern3)+startPattern3.length(), extract3.indexOf(endPattern3));
    extract4 = extract4.substring(extract4.indexOf(startPattern4)+startPattern4.length(), extract4.indexOf(endPattern4));
    extract5 = extract5.substring(extract5.indexOf(startPattern5)+startPattern5.length(), extract5.indexOf(endPattern5));

 String s = ("BLOPABP"+extract1) + ("\nBLOPCALL"+extract2) +("\nBLOPEXP"+extract3) +("\nBLOPHEAD"+extract4)+("\nBLOPMAJ"+extract5);

return s;
  }
```

How would I tidy up the code above into some sort of loop? Basically I have a file that i'm reading and extract the data within the tags and I'm passing the tags into this TagHandler method and returning the extracted data as a string with the tag headers without the "< START >" and "< END TAG"> leaving only the header on the start tag.

Comment: You can use an array instead of so many variables , I suppose !!!

Comment: By the usage of an `array` and a `for-loop`.

Comment: could u show me how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this, optimize it if you can :

```
public String handleTag(String buf, String[] attrList) {
    StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder();
    final String[] prefix = {"BLOPABP","\nBLOPCALL","\nBLOPEXP",
                       "\nBLOPHEAD","\nBLOPMAJ"};
    for(int i=0;i<attrList.length;i++){
        String startPattern = START+attrList[i]+">";
        String endPattern = END+attrList[i]+">";
        String extract = new String(buf);
        extract = extract.substring(
                extract.indexOf(startPattern)+startPattern.length(), 
                extract.indexOf(endPattern));
        temp.append(prefix[i%5]+extract);
    }

  return temp.toString();
}
```

Comment: wow thanks man! this actually worked! but my question is why is there a modulo sign at the line "temp.append(prefix[i%5]+extract);"

Comment: I just wanted to ensure that if `attrList.length > 5`, `prefix[i%5]` won't throw `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` ..

Comment: how would u write it without the modulo?

Comment: would u just add a try and catch block?

Comment: What purpose would it serve ? If anything greater than `5` , then obviously you will be short of prefixes !!! I will put a check then , rather than try-catch ..

Comment: I actually get what you said there. Another question, How would you make the prefix array dynamic? Like I want to add headers in main and pass it to the taghandler method?

Answer (score 1):

Here you go. This should do what you want.

```
public class TagHandler {

private final String START = "<START ";
private final String END = "<END ";

public String handleTag(String buf, String[] attrList) {

    String[] blop = {"BLOPABP", "BLOPCALL", "BLOPEXP", "BLOPHEAD", "BLOPMAJ"};
    String s = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < attrList.length; i++) {
        String startPattern = START+attrList[i]+">";
        String endPattern = END+attrList[i]+">";
        String extract = buf.substring(buf.indexOf(startPattern)+startPattern.length(), buf.indexOf(endPattern));
        s += blop[i]+extract;
        if (i < attrList.length-1) {
            s +=  "\n";
        }
    }
    return s;

}

}
```

Look out for an out of bounds exception, if `attrList` has more than 5 elements.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. You can replace `= new ArrayList<String>` with `= new ArrayList<>()` if you're using java 7.

```
private final String START = "<START ";
private final String END = "<END ";
List<String> startPatterns = new ArrayList<String>();//can use ArrayList<> instead if java 1.7
List<String> stringExtracts = new ArrayList<String>();
final String[] tags = new String[]{"BLOPABP","\nBLOPCALL","\nBLOPEXP","\nBLOPHEAD","\nBLOPMAJ"};

public String handleTag(String buf, String[] attrList) {
    int numPatterns = tags.length;
    String s;
    String extract = new String(buf);
    for(int i=0; i<numPatterns; i++){
        String startPattern = START+attrList[i]+">";
        startPatterns.add(startPattern);
        String endPattern = END+attrList[i]+">";
        endPatterns.add(endPattern);
        String extract = extract.substring(extract.indexOf(startPattern)+startPattern.length(), extract.indexOf(endPattern));
        stringExtracts.add(extract);
        s += tags[i] + extract;
    }
    return s;
}
```

This assumes that you need access to the individual startPatterns, endPatterns and stringExtracts again, not just s. If you only need s though then discard the ArrayLists - it will work like this:

```
private final String START = "<START ";
private final String END = "<END ";
final String[] tags = new String[]{"BLOPABP","\nBLOPCALL","\nBLOPEXP","\nBLOPHEAD","\nBLOPMAJ"};

public String handleTag(String buf, String[] attrList) {
    int numPatterns = tags.length;
    String s;
    String extract = new String(buf);
    for(int i=0; i<numPatterns; i++){
        String startPattern = START+attrList[i]+">";
        String endPattern = END+attrList[i]+">";
        String extract = extract.substring(extract.indexOf(startPattern)+startPattern.length(), extract.indexOf(endPattern));
        s += tags[i] + extract;
    }
    return s;
}
```